# How to automatically set the value of an input box to the opposite number when there's an input in any of two input boxes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's say we have 2 input boxes:

1. num1
2. num2

When the user inputs a number in any of the 2 input boxes, what we want to happen is automatically set the value of the other input box to the opposite sign of the number.

Examples:

- User inputs 1 in num1. The value of num2 should automatically be set
  to -1.
- User inputs -1 in num1. The value of num2 should automatically be set
  to 1.

How can we achieve this when using AngularJS 1.x?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do this:

1. In your controller put a watch on the values of num1 and num2. It might look something like this (assume $scope is injected in your controller)

Example HTML

```
<input type="number" ng-model="num1">
<input type="number" ng-model="num2">
```

Example JS

```
$scope.$watch('num1', function(newVal){
  $scope.num2 = - newVal;
}

$scope.$watch('num2', function(newVal){
  $scope.num1 = - newVal;
}
```

This way is preferable if you intend to reuse the controller with several views or there is an inherent relationships between the model data (num1 and num2). The watches will fire if the number are change for any reason (other bindings, explicit changes in javascript, etc).

2. In on your input have an ng-change set the value in an angular expression

Example HTML

```
<input type="number" ng-model="num1" ng-change="num2=-num1">
<input type="number" ng-model="num2" ng-change="num1=-num2">
```

This way is preferable if you only are only care about one number, or this logic only belongs in the view. It can also be more efficient, since it hooks the change event instead of doing and equivalence check every digest cycle. However, this means that if one of the number is changed though any means other than changing that input box the change will not be reflected. Credit to Manatax for pointing most of the benefits out in the comments below.

Comment: The second example would be a correct and efficient way to do it for the question asked.

Comment: @Manatax In my opinion both ways are correct. While I also lean a little toward the second way in most cases which one you use (and is more correct) depends on the modeled data and if the relationship should exist exclusively in the view or if it reflects the nature of the data. Given that the question doesn't provide context (which is fine) I figure both ways are worth mentioning.

Comment: I agree, it's just that ng-change is only called on the event change, but watch is constantly evaluated. If you put a function call instead of the expression and do your data modeling on the controller it would be proper and more efficient.

Comment: Good point. Edited the explanation to detail the pluses and minuses of those differences as well.